# Bibliography in Revtex not only show Journal but also arxiv source

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

One of my bibtex entries contains both journal field and eprint field like:

```
@ARTICLE{
  journal = {Nature},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint = {1105.1234}
}
```

I found Revtex4.1 format the bibliography to also show the arXiv source like:

```
... Nature 106, 6789 (2012), arXiv:1105.1234
```

But the article is published, so ony journal name, but not arXiv name, should show.

Are there any options that I should use to tell it not to show arXiv source?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I don't specify any style. The documentation says "REVTeX 4.1 calls in a default BibTeX Style (.bst) file for each supported journal"

Comment: If I explicitly use \\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}, arXiv source still there.

Comment: ArXiv name is already unneeded, hence it can be commented, can't it?

Comment: Yes, but I have many entries. They are directly downloaded from website. I don't want to comment it each time. Just want to find an easier way.

Comment: I know it might be late and the question is closed, but I was looking for a solution to the same problem and I found it. When you declare the documentclasss, you have to use the `noeprint` option, for example: `\documentclass[pra,aps,noeprint]{revtex4-1}`

Comment: @justmyfault Thanks. You are so kind to provide feedbacks. Much better than those who closed the question.

Comment: This question and @justmyfault's solution were very helpful to me. It's a shame this question was closed. It should be reopened such that the solution above can be written as proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has been reopened, I'm posting my previous comment as an answer.

The revtex option that disables the arXiv e-print identifiers in the bibliography is `noeprint`, which can be set, e.g., when declaring the document class:

```
\documentclass[pra,aps,noeprint]{revtex4-2}
```

For future reference, a useful summary document that explains revtex options is available on CTAN at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/auguide/summary4-2.pdf.

Comment: Is there a way to have the arXiv entry show up when the article is not published yet (i.e. when the journal entry is empty), while preventing it from showing up in every other instance? The documentation you mentioned does not seem to say anything about that, as far as I've seen it.

Comment: @LucasBaldo Personally I'd just fill the journal field with the arXiv ref.  The class doesn't offer any finer control, the `noeprint` switch just passes a boolean to the bst that either always or never prints the `eprint`.

Comment: @LucasBaldo I would also like to do that, but I do not think it is possible, so usually I just do what Dai Bowen suggested